# Stuck on the loop of npm fund and npm audit upon react-bootstrap and react-table install

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am working on a project where I need to create a table so I tried adding react-bootstrap and then react-table6. Both gave me errors about npm fund and npm audit so I ran npm install --no-fund which gave me the error related to npm audit so I tried fixing it with npm audit fix which led me to npm fund error again. If I force fix the npm audit, my react app is not starting now. My machine is Windows 8 64 bit. What am I doing wrong?